# how to solve this syntax error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pymysql

I am trying to connect jupyter to mysql database using this syntax:

```
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:mother@123@localhost:3306/united_nations
```

but i am getting the below syntax error:

```
MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

I was expecting to connect jupyter notebook to mysql database

Comment: If you have `@` in the password, I think you need to escape it as `%40` so it's not confused with the `@` that separates the password from the hostname.

Comment: So use `mother%40123`